# How to use firefox developer edition console while debugging?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-developer-tools

I was testing out [Firefox Developer Edition](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/developer/) today and noticed that while I could initially execute code in the javascript console, when I set a breakpoint in the javascript and started stepping through code, the console would become inactive (I can type in it, but pressing "enter" results in a newline instead of issuing the command) until I pressed "continue" and was no longer stepping through code.

In chrome, I appreciate the ability to execute javascript via the console in the context of the code I'm stepping through. Is this possible in Firefox Developer Edition? Thanks!

Comment: In firebug you can do this on the right hand side while stepping through the code, I haven't used the dev edition but perhaps you can do the same but as a different spot

Comment: I do believe that it's just a bug since in this video http://youtu.be/OS4AxYFLCIE console works just normally.

Answer (score 1):

All,
I just restarted Firefox, and the console is working while I'm debugging. I think I just hit a bug originally, which would explain why the console wasn't executing commands when I posted this answer. Thanks for the replies/comments!

Comment: I had the same problem. I need to restart Firefox often :( @Firefox, can you please release a fix ? :)

Answer (score 0):

The debugger is similar to Firebug and you can add an expression to the right side window, it says "Add watch expression". If you copy a line in there while stepping through your code, it will evaluate it with context to the current code.

[image]

I think this question is off topic but I will answer it just so you know

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Executing code and adding a watch expression are similar, but not the same thing. If I wanted to call functions in my code for example, I don't think I could do that with a watch expression. I think it may be a bug as @Roland Bertolom referred to earlier.

Comment: @Daniel have you tried calling a function in there? it should work, I don't see why it wouldn't work.

Comment: it is now. I think when I initially tried it wasn't. Maybe it required the restart that resulted in the console working again.